# How did Marvin the Martian end up on Earth?

Tags: looney-tunes

How did Marvin the Martian end up on Earth? In the early Looney Tunes cartoons he is found on Mars, but the later ones have him on Earth. Is it ever explained how he got there?

Comment: He hitched a ride on Mark Watney's ship and came here to grow potatos.

Comment: He had a spaceship if memory serves

Comment: It took them two years to build a ladder long enough to reach the remains of the Moon so that Bugs Bunny could climb back down to Earth. It would have been a shame to rltear it doen right away, so Marvin must have used it, too.

Answer (score 6):

Marvin has a variety of spaceships. His people seem to be engaged in active exploration of the inner solar system, of which Earth is part.

**[Haredevil Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haredevil_Hare) (1948)** (Marvin's first appearance).
[image]
Note the slogan - "*Mars to Moon Expeditionary Force*"

---

**[The Hasty Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hasty_Hare) (1952)** - (Marvin's first trip to Earth).
[image]

---

**[Hare-Way to the Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hare-Way_to_the_Stars) (1958)**
[image]

---

**[Spaced Out Bunny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_Out_Bunny) (1980)**
[image]

---

**[Another Froggy Evening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Froggy_Evening#Sequel) (1995)**
[image]

---

**[Marvin the Martian in the Third Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_the_Martian_in_the_Third_Dimension) (1997)**
[image]

Comment: That last one looks like a Cobra MkIII